# Rails - Sum of a calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a formula that figures out a price based on whether or not it has liner and I need to total of all items. I am guessing I should take that formula and add it to the controller so I can get the sum, but I can't seem to figure out how to add it to the model.

Model ##this doesn't work##

```
def liner
 (((2 * order_item.length) + (2 * order_item.width)) * order_item.height + (order_item.length + order_item.width)) * current_user.company.rate
end
```

Controller

```
def edit
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  @order_items = OrderItem.where(order_id: @order)
end
```

View ##this all works except for the sum at the bottom##

```
<% if @order_items.exists? %>
  <div class="well">

    <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <%= order_item.liner.present? ? (order_item.fitting.name + ' w/ Liner') : order_item.fitting.name %>
              </td>
              <td>
                <%= order_item.length %>"L
                  <%= order_item.width %>"W
                    <%= order_item.height %>"H
              </td>
              <td><%= order_item.quantity %> @ (<%= order_item.liner.present? ? number_to_currency((((2 * order_item.length) + (2 * order_item.width)) * order_item.height + (order_item.length + order_item.width)) * current_user.company.rate) : number_to_currency((((2 * order_item.length) + (2 * order_item.width)) * order_item.height) * current_user.company.rate) %>) =</td>
              <td>
                <td><%= order_item.liner.present? ? number_to_currency(((((2 * order_item.length) + (2 * order_item.width)) * order_item.height + (order_item.length + order_item.width)) * current_user.company.rate) * order_item.quantity) : number_to_currency(((((2 * order_item.length) + (2 * order_item.width)) * order_item.height) * current_user.company.rate) * order_item.quantity) %></td>
              <td>
                <%= link_to '<i class="material-icons">clear</i>'.html_safe, order_item, class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger', role: 'button', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

      <% end %>
    <p><%= @order_items.sum(&:liner) %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

I was thinking I need two formulas in the model...one for w/ liner and one for w/o liner. Then when I add them to the view, I can get the sum of each.

Every time I try using the Model, I can't get it right...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First define your method inside the model:

```
#File: app/models/client.rb

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    def liner
        # your code here
    end
end
```

To test it, open a rails console, go to your app folder and type:

```
rails c
```

Inside the console, get one instance and try your method:

```
c = Client.find(1)
c.liner
```

This way, you are testing if your mehtod works fine. Later you can use it in you controller or your view.

Comment: Well I've just showed you how I start the process. First you create a method in you Model, and then you check its funcion on the `rails console` and then you can think in add call to that method in you controller or view. The basic idea, is to solve the model method definition first, and be sure that works fine.

Comment: Your post was as basic as possible...not helpful. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Your current liner method won't work because it doesn't have access to the current user. Also in a model method, you don't use the model instance in the method. You could try passing the user to the method.

```
class OrderItem
  def price_with_liner(user)
    (((2 * length) + (2 * width)) * height + (length + width)) * user.company.rate
  end
```

To abstract some of the logic from the view, you can create helper methods which will make the view more readable and facilitate debugging. Below should get you started.

helpers/order_items_helper.rb

```
module OrderItemsHelper

  def price(order_item, user)
    if order_item.liner.present? 
      number_to_currency(order_item.price_with_liner(user))
    else 
      number_to_currency(order_item.price_without_liner(user))
    end
  end

end
```

view

```
<td><%= price(order_item, user) </td>
```

Comment: I will check this out when I get a chance later today. Thank you!